# Unexpected token function on jQuery structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS:

```
var interval=setInterval(function(){ $("#nav #nextslide").click()},10000);
$( ".gallery" ).on(
  mouseenter: function() {
      clearInterval(interval);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
     interval = setInterval(function(){ $("#nav #nextslide").click()},10000);
  }
);
```

But don't working. When I check it via DevTools, get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
```

About eror line:

```
mouseenter: function() {
```

Comment: It's invalid syntax. Objects are created with braces - JavaScript does not otherwise have a concept of "named parameters".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a trivial syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to use [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    $("#nav #nextslide").click();
}, 10000);
$(".gallery").on('hover', function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
}, function () {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        $("#nav #nextslide").click();
    }, 10000);
});
```

### OR

Modify your code as

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    $("#nav #nextslide").click();
}, 10000);
$(".gallery").mouseenter(function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        $("#nav #nextslide").click();
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Yes, setInterval working on this solution. But not working on hover function.

Comment: @user3099199, both solutions are equivalent. Even zavg solution should work

Answer (score 1):

You should pass *object* with fields `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to the `on` function:

```
$( ".gallery" ).on({
  mouseenter: function() {
      clearInterval(interval);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
     interval = setInterval(function(){ $("#nav #nextslide").click()},10000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you not syntax error now but not working.

Comment: "Not working" is very vague formulation

Comment: Not active setInterval so not working on hover clearInterval.

Comment: @user3099199 look at Satpal solution